# Signal 11, segmentation fault on iphone App exit

Tags: iphone, segmentation-fault, exit

I have an iphone app.  It seems to run fine.  When I connect to a provisioned iphone to Xcode and run the App, the console log in the Organizer window, always complains about a Segmentation fault when quitting the app with the home key.

Has anyone else seen this, and do you have an idea of what the problem might be?  I use a thread to load web pages in the backround, but I stop the thread when exiting.

My app does save some persistent information.  When I use the build and analyze function I get some 2 potential memory leaks, but in each case I'm allocating an object and keeping it in an array.

Any ideas, or is this normal?

Comment: NSZombieEnabled really helped me finding a crash I couldn't find before.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try running your application with NSZombieEnabled. This will tell you if you're over releasing any object. To enable zombies do the following:

> 1. Choose Project > Edit Active Executable to open the executable Info
>      window.
> 2. Click Arguments.
> 3. Click the add (+) button in the “Variables to be set in the
>      environment” section.
> 4. Enter NSZombieEnabled in the Name column and YES in the Value column.
> 5. Make sure that the checkmark forthe NSZombieEnabled entry is selected.

Comment: With NSZombieEnabled, where should I set a breakpoint to catch the problem?

With this setting, me program terminates early with the message: CFString autorelease: message sent to deallocated instance.

I'd like to break when the message is sent to a deallocated string, so I can figure out which string.

Thanks,
Gerry

Comment: With Zombies enabled.  My code faults inside the [parser parse] line from the code below.  This bit happens on an NSThread.  Any ideas as to what would cause a problem.  My foundCharacters routine is not hit.

Thanks,
Gerry  (code in next comment)

Comment: NSURL *nsurl = [NSURL URLWithString:query];
 NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl];
 
 data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
 
 NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:data];
 [parser setDelegate:self];
 [parser setShouldProcessNamespaces:NO];
 [parser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:NO];
 [parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
 errorStr = nil;
 if ( [parser parse] == YES )
             // stuff

Comment: I still don't have the complete answer.  Running with NSZombies does cause an early crash in my program which should indicate a bug.  The problem is that it happens in NSXMLParser which is outside of my control.  Other multiple releases may persist, but I have to keep sectioning the code to find them.  Sigh.

Comment: When you say it happens inside [parser parse] does it give you more information than that? I'm wondering if it's a problem with your data variable. I can't remember of the top of my head if you have to retain the result of  [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error] i.e. [ [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error] retain]. Can you give it a try? Remember to release when you're finished.

Answer (score 0):

Upon exit your application can over-release an object try dumping each object before releasing it or do some debugging in dealloc method.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are releasing some object more times than its retain count. Comment out `-release` calls in your `dealloc` methods (or elsewhere) until you find the culprit.

Then uncomment-out that call and look elsewhere in your code where you are trying to over-release that object.

If you are using convenience methods, for example, (e.g. `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"..."]`) as opposed to `alloc-init` methods (e.g. `[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"..."]`) the resulting convenience object is autoreleased and should not be manually released.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was uididfaker and locationholic from cydia, and after uninstalling them xcode run on my iphone just fine.