# Application '' exited abnormally with signal 11: Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: iphone, ios5

> Application '' exited abnormally with signal 11: Segmentation fault:
>   11

What might the problem that causes this be?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805127/ipad-app-exited-abnormally-with-signal-11-segmentation-fault-11 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1849929/signal-11-segmentation-fault-on-iphone-app-exit

Comment: please suggest me about search function in stack over flow

Comment: @jaydev There's a box in the top right corner of the browser window that search "search" in it. Type in your search terms and hit enter.

Answer (score 7):

These errors occur when your program tries to access the memory location of an object that no longer exists, an object which at some earlier point in the application's lifetime has had its memory released back into the heap.

If you can track down which variable is being accessed at the time of the crash, through the use of judicious comments or, better still, a debugger, then you will have a potentially easier time fixing the bugs.

In the meantime, re-read Apple's excellent [Memory Management guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/memorymgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html), which goes into memory management issues in greater detail than can fit into this comment field.

Comment: I have the same error happening, but the weird thing is that if I run the same application with an ad hoc certificate, it works fine. After I sent an update to the AppStore, it stopped working (this is what I get right after I open my app).

Comment: The Dev Profile seems to allow you to play a little faster / loose with the memory management.

Comment: @K2Digital is there some place I can read about these differences between the Dev and Distr profiles when managing memory?