# Crash on iOS7, but works fine on iOS6 devices

Tags: ios, ios7.1

Team,

I am upgrading the application to iOS7. I am seeing inconsistent crashes in my application when I pushed my app to background and play around with other apps and bring my application to foreground and then perform some actions, it crashes.. I am not able to reproduce the crash without pushing the application to background.

Device Logs:

```
Apr 18 04:15:36 iPhone-5C ADTCommercial[7516] <Notice>: +[DataUtil isDiscountAvalableFor:] - set number of records: 0 for jobLineType: Rental
Apr 18 04:15:37 iPhone-5C ADTCommercial[7516] <Notice>: AmountThresholdValue: 0.000000 for type: Parts
Apr 18 04:15:37 iPhone-5C ADTCommercial[7516] <Notice>: AmountThresholdValue: 0.000000 for type: Parts
Apr 18 04:15:37 iPhone-5C ADTCommercial[7516] <Notice>: AmountThresholdValue: 0.000000 for type: Labor
Apr 18 04:15:37 iPhone-5C ADTCommercial[7516] <Notice>: AmountThresholdValue: 0.000000 for type: Labor
Apr 18 04:15:37 iPhone-5C ADTCommercial[7516] <Notice>: AmountThresholdValue: 0.000000 for type: TripFee
Apr 18 04:15:37 iPhone-5C ADTCommercial[7516] <Notice>: AmountThresholdValue: 0.000000 for type: TripFee
Apr 18 04:15:37 iPhone-5C ADTCommercial[7516] <Notice>: PercentageThreshold: 0.000000 for type: Parts
Apr 18 04:15:37 iPhone-5C ADTCommercial[7516] <Notice>: PercentageThreshold: 0.000000 for type: Parts
Apr 18 04:15:37 iPhone-5C ADTCommercial[7516] <Notice>: PercentageThreshold: 0.000000 for type: Labor
Apr 18 04:15:37 iPhone-5C ADTCommercial[7516] <Notice>: PercentageThreshold: 0.000000 for type: Labor
Apr 18 04:15:37 iPhone-5C ADTCommercial[7516] <Notice>: PercentageThreshold: 0.000000 for type: TripFee
Apr 18 04:15:37 iPhone-5C ADTCommercial[7516] <Notice>: PercentageThreshold: 0.000000 for type: TripFee
Apr 18 04:15:37 iPhone-5C ADTCommercial[7516] <Notice>: -[ADT_JobWrapUpInvoiceSummary(Custom) writeToClearAppointment] --------- strComment -> Fhf
Apr 18 04:15:37 iPhone-5C ADTCommercial[7516] <Notice>: number of rows: 0
Apr 18 04:15:37 iPhone-5C ADTCommercial[7516] <Notice>: [AMPCSPManager save:] successful; record ID: 744, message ID: psahu-54-1397808937614
Apr 18 04:15:37 iPhone-5C ADTCommercial[7516] <Notice>: [AMPReConnectionThread wakeupReconnectionThread:]
Apr 18 04:15:37 iPhone-5C ADTCommercial[7516] <Notice>: [AMPMessageDispatcherThread handleMessage:] message {psahu-54-1397808937614} received on Outbound-msg-dispatcher for processing, MIM: 7, MID: 0
Apr 18 04:15:37 iPhone-5C ADTCommercial[7516] <Notice>: [AMPReConnectionThread wakeupReconnectionThread:]
Apr 18 04:15:37 iPhone-5C ADTCommercial[7516] <Notice>: Total pending messages to be sent: 1
Apr 18 04:15:37 iPhone-5C ADTCommercial[7516] <Notice>: CSP sending pending message: psahu-54-1397808937614, recId: 744
Apr 18 04:15:37 iPhone-5C ADTCommercial[7516] <Notice>: [AMPSocketsSender executeSendImpl:] send: ID: psahu-54-1397808937614, MIM/D: TX/none, size: 199 bytes, priority: 4, ts: 2014-04-18 08:15:37 +0000
Apr 18 04:15:37 iPhone-5C ReportCrash[7532] <Notice>: ReportCrash acting against PID 7516
Apr 18 04:15:37 iPhone-5C ReportCrash[7532] <Notice>: Formulating crash report for process ADTCommercial[7516]
Apr 18 04:15:37 iPhone-5C com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.pega.adt.commercial[0xaea4][7516]) <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:com.pega.adt.commercial[0xaea4]) Job appears to have crashed: Segmentation fault: 11
Apr 18 04:15:37 iPhone-5C backboardd[28] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.pega.adt.commercial[0xaea4]' exited abnormally with signal 11: Segmentation fault: 11
Apr 18 04:15:38 iPhone-5C ReportCrash[7532] <Notice>: Saved crashreport to /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/ADTCommercial_2014-04-18-041537_iPhone-5C.ips using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 501 egid: 0
Apr 18 04:15:56 iPhone-5C kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[7533] Container: /private/var/mobile/Applications/E1DD29B0-D860-4546-AA39-4849262013B8 (sandbox)
Apr 18 04:15:56 iPhone-5C backboardd[28] <Error>: HID: The 'Passive' connection
```

Crash report:

```
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3a230626 objc_msgSend + 6
1   UIFoundation                    0x377577e6 __25-[_UICache objectForKey:]_block_invoke + 54
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3a70fd3c _dispatch_client_callout + 20
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x3a7146be _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 22
4   UIFoundation                    0x377576fc -[_UICache objectForKey:] + 148
5   UIFoundation                    0x3773561e UINewFontIgnoringLinkCheck + 194
6   UIFoundation                    0x3773594c +[UIFont systemFontOfSize:traits:] + 16
7   ADTCommercial                   0x003613f4 -[AMPGeneratedListViewController viewDidLoad] (AMPGeneratedListViewController.m:37)
8   ADTCommercial                   0x001a1ec4 -[ADT_CollectPayment(Custom) viewDidLoad] (ADT_CollectPayment+Custom.m:60)
9   UIKit                           0x3263066e -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1418
10  UIKit                           0x32631d8e -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 134
11  ADTCommercial                   0x00385f20 -[AMPViewManager loadView] (AMPViewManager.m:104)
12  ADTCommercial                   0x0037a3ae -[AMPScreenManager showScreen:withRow:createScreen:reloadPolicy:doReset:isModal:animated:navigationController:] (AMPScreenManager.m:639)
13  ADTCommercial                   0x0034f058 +[AMPStandardActions gotoAction:reloadPolicy:transactionStateChange:addToHistory:] (AMPStandardActions.m:40)
14  ADTCommercial                   0x0012d78c -[ADT_JobWrapUpInvoiceSummary(Custom) btnNextPressed:] (ADT_JobWrapUpInvoiceSummary+Custom.m:762)
15  UIKit                           0x322f66c2 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 86
16  UIKit                           0x322f665e -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 34
17  UIKit                           0x322f662e -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 42
18  UIKit                           0x322e1d76 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 370
19  UIKit                           0x322f6076 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 590
20  UIKit                           0x322f5d48 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 524
21  UIKit                           0x322f0ca2 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 754
22  UIKit                           0x322c5e70 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 192
23  UIKit                           0x322c453c _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 7116
24  CoreFoundation                  0x2fa5cfe4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 12
25  CoreFoundation                  0x2fa5c4aa __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 202
26  CoreFoundation                  0x2fa5ac9a __CFRunLoopRun + 626
27  CoreFoundation                  0x2f9c57a4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
28  CoreFoundation                  0x2f9c5586 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
29  GraphicsServices                0x349326ce GSEventRunModal + 134
30  UIKit                           0x3232488c UIApplicationMain + 1132
31  ADTCommercial                   0x0006a96c main (main.m:17)
32  libdyld.dylib                   0x3a724ab4 start + 0

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a7c8804 kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3a717050 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 228
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3a7112de _dispatch_mgr_thread + 34

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a7c8a50 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a7c8848 mach_msg + 36
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2fa5c61c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 152
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2fa5ad3c __CFRunLoopRun + 788
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2f9c57a4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2f9c5586 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
6   Foundation                      0x303b8492 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 250
7   Foundation                      0x30409254 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 76
8   ADTCommercial                   0x0024a1f2 -[iOSScheduler main] (iOSScheduler.m:100)
9   Foundation                      0x3047aa0a __NSThread__main__ + 1058
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a842956 _pthread_body + 138
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a8428c6 _pthread_start + 98
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a840ae4 thread_start + 4

Thread 3 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a7c8a50 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a7c8848 mach_msg + 36
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2fa5c61c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 152
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2fa5ad3c __CFRunLoopRun + 788
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2f9c57a4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2f9c5586 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
6   Foundation                      0x3040523c +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 316
7   Foundation                      0x3047aa0a __NSThread__main__ + 1058
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a842956 _pthread_body + 138
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a8428c6 _pthread_start + 98
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a840ae4 thread_start + 4

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a7db434 __select + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x2fa60516 __CFSocketManager + 482
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a842956 _pthread_body + 138
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a8428c6 _pthread_start + 98
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a840ae4 thread_start + 4

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a7daf2c __psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a841f9c _pthread_cond_wait + 576
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a841d54 pthread_cond_timedwait_relative_np + 12
3   Foundation                      0x303c1f12 -[NSCondition waitUntilDate:] + 282
4   ADTCommercial                   0x00323c02 -[AMPSocketsSender executeSendWithAck:] (AMPSocketsSender.m:282)
5   ADTCommercial                   0x003234bc -[AMPSocketsSender send:] (AMPSocketsSender.m:214)
6   ADTCommercial                   0x00318bb6 -[AMPOutboundDispatcherProcess actualSend:] (AMPOutboundDispatcherProcess.m:130)
7   ADTCommercial                   0x003069e0 -[AMPCSPManager performActionOnMessages:action:messageLimit:] (AMPCSPManager.m:295)
8   ADTCommercial                   0x0031898c -[AMPOutboundDispatcherProcess dispatchMessage:] (AMPOutboundDispatcherProcess.m:99)
9   ADTCommercial                   0x0030f140 -[AMPMessageDispatcherThread handleMessage:] (AMPMessageDispatcherThread.m:87)
10  Foundation                      0x3047ac1e __NSThreadPerformPerform + 382
11  CoreFoundation                  0x2fa5cfe4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 12
12  CoreFoundation                  0x2fa5c4aa __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 202
13  CoreFoundation                  0x2fa5ac9a __CFRunLoopRun + 626
14  CoreFoundation                  0x2f9c57a4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
15  CoreFoundation                  0x2f9c5586 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
16  Foundation                      0x303b8492 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 250
17  ADTCommercial                   0x0030f4a8 -[AMPMessageDispatcherThread main] (AMPMessageDispatcherThread.m:117)
18  Foundation                      0x3047aa0a __NSThread__main__ + 1058
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a842956 _pthread_body + 138
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a8428c6 _pthread_start + 98
21  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a840ae4 thread_start + 4

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a7c8a50 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a7c8848 mach_msg + 36
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2fa5c61c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 152
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2fa5ad3c __CFRunLoopRun + 788
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2f9c57a4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2f9c5586 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
6   Foundation                      0x303b8492 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 250
7   ADTCommercial                   0x0030f4a8 -[AMPMessageDispatcherThread main] (AMPMessageDispatcherThread.m:117)
8   Foundation                      0x3047aa0a __NSThread__main__ + 1058
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a842956 _pthread_body + 138
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a8428c6 _pthread_start + 98
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a840ae4 thread_start + 4

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a7c8a50 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a7c8848 mach_msg + 36
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2fa5c61c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 152
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2fa5ad3c __CFRunLoopRun + 788
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2f9c57a4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2f9c5586 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
6   Foundation                      0x303b8492 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 250
7   ADTCommercial                   0x0030f4a8 -[AMPMessageDispatcherThread main] (AMPMessageDispatcherThread.m:117)
8   Foundation                      0x3047aa0a __NSThread__main__ + 1058
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a842956 _pthread_body + 138
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a8428c6 _pthread_start + 98
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a840ae4 thread_start + 4

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a7daf2c __psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a841f62 _pthread_cond_wait + 518
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a842d9c pthread_cond_wait + 36
3   Foundation                      0x3040533a -[NSCondition wait] + 190
4   ADTCommercial                   0x0032316c -[AMPSocketsSender main:] (AMPSocketsSender.m:187)
5   Foundation                      0x3047aa0a __NSThread__main__ + 1058
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a842956 _pthread_body + 138
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a8428c6 _pthread_start + 98
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a840ae4 thread_start + 4

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a7c8a50 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a7c8848 mach_msg + 36
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2fa5c61c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 152
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2fa5ad3c __CFRunLoopRun + 788
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2f9c57a4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2f9c5586 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
6   Foundation                      0x303b8492 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 250
7   ADTCommercial                   0x0031923a -[AMPReConnectionThread main:] (AMPReConnectionThread.m:77)
8   Foundation                      0x3047aa0a __NSThread__main__ + 1058
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a842956 _pthread_body + 138
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a8428c6 _pthread_start + 98
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a840ae4 thread_start + 4

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a7c8a50 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a7c8848 mach_msg + 36
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2fa5c61c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 152
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2fa5ad3c __CFRunLoopRun + 788
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2f9c57a4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2f9c5586 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
6   Foundation                      0x303b8492 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 250
7   ADTCommercial                   0x00320742 -[AMPSocketsConnectorHandler main:] (AMPSocketsConnectorHandler.m:71)
8   Foundation                      0x3047aa0a __NSThread__main__ + 1058
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a842956 _pthread_body + 138
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a8428c6 _pthread_start + 98
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a840ae4 thread_start + 4

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a7c8aa0 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3a715f04 _dispatch_group_wait_slow + 168
2   ADTCommercial                   0x003bcdaa +[DDLog lt_log:] (DDLog.m:946)
3   ADTCommercial                   0x003bb9a4 __40+[DDLog queueLogMessage:asynchronously:]_block_invoke (DDLog.m:449)
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x3a70fd50 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 8
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x3a714cb8 _dispatch_queue_drain + 484
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x3a711c6a _dispatch_queue_invoke + 38
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x3a7155ee _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 74
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x3a7158d8 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 52
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a840c14 _pthread_wqthread + 296
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a840ad8 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a7c8a50 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a7c8848 mach_msg + 36
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2fa5c61c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 152
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2fa5ad3c __CFRunLoopRun + 788
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2f9c57a4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2fa093c6 CFRunLoopRun + 94
6   CoreMotion                      0x300844fc ___lldb_unnamed_function1426$$CoreMotion + 724
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a842956 _pthread_body + 138
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a8428c6 _pthread_start + 98
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a840ae4 thread_start + 4

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a7dbc70 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a840c1e _pthread_wqthread + 306
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a840ad8 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 14:
0   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a743fec _vsnprintf + 336
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a743e90 vsnprintf + 68
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a79aeda __snprintf_chk + 18
3   libsystem_asl.dylib             0x3a736e62 asl_string_append_char_no_encoding + 106
4   libsystem_asl.dylib             0x3a73712c asl_string_append_internal + 488
5   libsystem_asl.dylib             0x3a73b7ea asl_msg_to_string_raw + 218
6   libsystem_asl.dylib             0x3a735302 _asl_send_message + 1274
7   libsystem_asl.dylib             0x3a734c10 _asl_lib_vlog + 340
8   libsystem_asl.dylib             0x3a734ca4 asl_log + 36
9   ADTCommercial                   0x003b6c5a -[DDASLLogger logMessage:] (DDASLLogger.m:77)
10  ADTCommercial                   0x003bcffe __16+[DDLog lt_log:]_block_invoke (DDLog.m:940)
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x3a70fd50 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 8
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x3a714cb8 _dispatch_queue_drain + 484
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x3a711c6a _dispatch_queue_invoke + 38
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x3a7155ee _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 74
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x3a7158d8 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 52
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a840c14 _pthread_wqthread + 296
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a840ad8 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 15:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a7daf2c __psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a841f62 _pthread_cond_wait + 518
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a842ddc pthread_cond_timedwait + 40
3   ADTCommercial                   0x002632ae CPosixEvent::WaitEvent(long) (PosixThread.cpp:90)
4   ADTCommercial                   0x00263390 CMultiEvents::WaitForEvents(unsigned long, unsigned long, long) (PosixThread.cpp:132)
5   ADTCommercial                   0x00242ea4 CMCCommMgr::ConnectServer() (MCCommMgr.cpp:482)
6   ADTCommercial                   0x00242c3e CMCCommMgr::Run() (MCCommMgr.cpp:416)
7   ADTCommercial                   0x00242770 CMCCommMgr::CommMgrThread(void*) (MCCommMgr.cpp:555)
8   ADTCommercial                   0x002635f8 CPosixThread::MyTheadRoutine(void*) (PosixThread.cpp:288)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a842956 _pthread_body + 138
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a8428c6 _pthread_start + 98
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a840ae4 thread_start + 4

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x15f00190    r1: 0x328ed27d      r2: 0x00000018      r3: 0x00000000
    r4: 0x27d9c640    r5: 0x27d9cc5c      r6: 0x3c718e80      r7: 0x27d9c614
    r8: 0x377658eb    r9: 0x50000000     r10: 0x004d3eec     r11: 0x170f2f80
    ip: 0x3c2be868    sp: 0x27d9c610      lr: 0x377577eb      pc: 0x3a230626
  cpsr: 0x80000030
```

Thanks,
Ramesh

Comment: http://sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2008/09/22/objc_explain_So_you_crashed_in_objc_msgSend.html

Answer (score 2):

Checking your stack trace `exited abnormally with signal 11: Segmentation fault: 11` seems to be the crash

These errors occur when your program tries to access the memory location of an object that no longer exists, an object which at some earlier point in the application's lifetime has had its memory released back into the heap.

If you can track down which variable is being accessed at the time of the crash, through the use of judicious comments or, better still, a debugger, then you will have a potentially easier time fixing the bugs.

In the meantime, re-read Apple's excellent Memory Management guide, which goes into memory management issues in greater detail than can fit into this comment field.

Credit to Alex Reynolds for this on his answer on this [Application '' exited abnormally with signal 11: Segmentation fault: 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10026835/application-exited-abnormally-with-signal-11-segmentation-fault-11)