# Objective-C Cyclic Retainment Causes Crashes In Ad Hoc Distribution But Didn't Before

Tags: ios, xcode, crash

After reinstalling my XCode 4.3.2, my app's ad hoc distribution starts to cause crashes when running on IPad. After debugging and reading other stackoverflow threads, the problem turned out to be caused by cyclic retainment. Specifically, I was calling a method on the self object in a callback block. My question is why this problem never happened before. Is it some setting in XCode?

Comment: retain cycles are not likely to cause crashes. over-retaining something isn't dangerous like over-releasing. What is the actual exception message from the crash log?

Comment: FYI - why are you using Xcode 4? You must use at least Xcode 5 to send an app to Apple.

Comment: Over-retaining won’t crash immediately, but it will eventually cause your app to run out of memory and be killed by the system. And if you over-retain objects that have timers or are performing network operations, you could get some very weird behavior.

Comment: The crash message is : Application exited abnormally with signal 11: Segmentation fault: 11. The basic scenario is that the caller view controller calls an HTTP request sender with a callback block. The block contains some action to be taken by the caller. The block is saved by the request sender in a class variable. The callback is triggered when response is received. The reason I'm using Xcode 4 is that I have no time to upgrade my OSX for the moment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Application '' exited abnormally with signal 11: Segmentation fault: 11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10026835/application-exited-abnormally-with-signal-11-segmentation-fault-11)

Comment: The problem doesn't take place when the IPad is connected to my MAC and the program launched from XCode.