# put NSURL from NSUserDefauls to a NSSet

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Why does the following code throws an error:

```
NSUserDefaults *sharedDefaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"com.apple.example"];
NSURL *m = [sharedDefaults URLForKey:@"test"]; // just another fileURLWithPath

NSURL *c = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/Users/dummy/Documents"];
NSURL *d = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/Users/dummy/Pictures"];
NSSet *q = [NSSet setWithObjects:c, d, m, nil];
```

In particular, the error is:

```
Service exited due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Application '' exited abnormally with signal 11: Segmentation fault: 11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10026835/application-exited-abnormally-with-signal-11-segmentation-fault-11)

Comment: Try to print the object `c, d & m` before adding it to `NSSet`.

Comment: Which line exactly causes the crash?

Comment: The code seems fine, please provide the line number.