# Seeking Assistance for iOS App Crash Due to objc_msgSend

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, crash, crash-reports

I hope this message finds you well. We are currently facing a critical issue with the app on iOS, resulting in frequent crashes. After thorough analysis, we have identified a specific problem related to the objc_msgSend function. Below is a detailed crash report for your reference:

```
Date/Time:           2024-01-11 07:14:14.9204 -0800
Launch Time:         2024-01-11 07:09:04.0139 -0800
OS Version:          iPhone OS 17.2 (21C62)
Release Type:        User
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000010
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000010
VM Region Info: 0x10 is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 68719476720
REGION TYPE                 START - END      \[ VSIZE\] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
UNUSED SPACE AT START
\---\>  
commpage (reserved)     1000000000-7000000000 \[384.0G\] ---/--- SM=NUL  ...(unallocated)
Termination Reason: SIGNAL 11 Segmentation fault: 11
Terminating Process: exc handler \[12701\]

Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:   Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x1976f4820 objc_msgSend + 32
1   UIKitCore                              0x1a17fd2ac -\[UIViewController dealloc\] + 860
2   UIKitCore                              0x1a18c68d8 -\[UINavigationController dealloc\] + 296
3   UIKitCore                              0x1a1cac73c -\[\_UISplitViewControllerColumnContents .cxx_destruct\] + 44
4   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x1976f5374 object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object\*, objc_class\*) + 116
5   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x1976f509c objc_destructInstance + 80
6   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x1976f503c \_objc_rootDealloc + 80
7   CoreFoundation                         0x19f331fc8 cow_cleanup + 164
8   CoreFoundation                         0x19f331ed4 -\[\__NSDictionaryM dealloc\] + 148
9   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x1976f5374 object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object\*, objc_class\*) + 116
10  libobjc.A.dylib                        0x1976f509c objc_destructInstance + 80
11  libobjc.A.dylib                        0x1976f503c \_objc_rootDealloc + 80
12  UIKitCore                              0x1a1cac7c4 -\[UISplitViewControllerPanelImpl dealloc\] + 100
13  libobjc.A.dylib                        0x1976f5374 object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object\*, objc_class\*) + 116
14  libobjc.A.dylib                        0x1976f509c objc_destructInstance + 80
15  libobjc.A.dylib                        0x1976f503c \_objc_rootDealloc + 80
16  UIKitCore                              0x1a15d12b0 -\[UIResponder dealloc\] + 124
17  UIKitCore                              0x1a17fd3e4 -\[UIViewController dealloc\] + 1172
18  libobjc.A.dylib                        0x1976f2b74 AutoreleasePoolPage::releaseUntil(objc_object\*\*) + 196
19  libobjc.A.dylib                        0x1976f2a10 objc_autoreleasePoolPop + 260
20  UIKitCore                              0x1a15fc370 -\[\_UIAfterCACommitBlock run\] + 92
21  UIKitCore                              0x1a15fc140 -\[\_UIAfterCACommitQueue flush\] + 164
22  UIKitCore                              0x1a15fc058 \_runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 496
23  UIKitCore                              0x1a15fbde4 \_cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 100
24  UIKitCore                              0x1a15fbce0 \_UIApplicationFlushCATransaction + 72
25  UIKitCore                              0x1a15fb7e4 \_UIUpdateSequenceRun + 84
26  UIKitCore                              0x1a15faed4 schedulerStepScheduledMainSection + 144
27  UIKitCore                              0x1a15faf90 runloopSourceCallback + 92
28  CoreFoundation                         0x19f35d12c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 28
29  CoreFoundation                         0x19f35c3a8 \__CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 176
30  CoreFoundation                         0x19f35ab5c \__CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 244
31  CoreFoundation                         0x19f359898 \__CFRunLoopRun + 828
32  CoreFoundation                         0x19f359478 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 608
33  GraphicsServices                       0x1e28b24f8 GSEventRunModal + 164
34  UIKitCore                              0x1a177d62c -\[UIApplication \_run\] + 888
35  UIKitCore                              0x1a177cc68 UIApplicationMain + 340
36  SwiftUI                                0x1a418d4b8 0x1a3027000 + 18244792
37  SwiftUI                                0x1a418d2fc 0x1a3027000 + 18244348
38  SwiftUI                                0x1a3dfde90 0x1a3027000 + 14511760
39  LifeLog                                0x10228815c 0x1021e0000 + 688476
40  dyld                                   0x1c207edcc start + 2240

Thread 1 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1e69f5178 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1e69f4f10 mach_msg2_internal + 80
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1e69f4e28 mach_msg_overwrite + 436
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1e69f4c68 mach_msg + 24
4   CoreFoundation                         0x19f35bb1c \__CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160
5   CoreFoundation                         0x19f359a14 \__CFRunLoopRun + 1208
6   CoreFoundation                         0x19f359478 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 608
7   Foundation                             0x19e2ec48c -\[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:\] + 212
8   Foundation                             0x19e31974c -\[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:\] + 64
9   UIKitCore                              0x1a16df4a8 -\[UIEventFetcher threadMain\] + 420
10  Foundation                             0x19e36fde0 __NSThread__start__ + 732
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x2092204d4 \_pthread_start + 136
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x20921fa10 thread_start + 8

Thread 2 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1e69f5178 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1e69f4f10 mach_msg2_internal + 80
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1e69f4e28 mach_msg_overwrite + 436
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1e69f4c68 mach_msg + 24
4   CoreFoundation                         0x19f35bb1c \__CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160
5   CoreFoundation                         0x19f359a14 \__CFRunLoopRun + 1208
6   CoreFoundation                         0x19f359478 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 608
7   CFNetwork                              0x1a0657060 0x1a03fd000 + 2465888
8   Foundation                             0x19e36fde0 __NSThread__start__ + 732
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x2092204d4 \_pthread_start + 136
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x20921fa10 thread_start + 8

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x20921f9fc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x20921f9fc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.SwiftUI.AsyncRenderer
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1e69f5178 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1e69f4f10 mach_msg2_internal + 80
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1e69f4e28 mach_msg_overwrite + 436
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1e69f4c68 mach_msg + 24
4   CoreFoundation                         0x19f35bb1c \__CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160
5   CoreFoundation                         0x19f359a14 \__CFRunLoopRun + 1208
6   CoreFoundation                         0x19f359478 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 608
7   Foundation                             0x19e2ec48c -\[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:\] + 212
8   Foundation                             0x19e2ea884 -\[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run\] + 64
9   SwiftUI                                0x1a37cca44 0x1a3027000 + 8018500
10  SwiftUI                                0x1a37ccb78 0x1a3027000 + 8018808
11  Foundation                             0x19e36fde0 __NSThread__start__ + 732
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x2092204d4 \_pthread_start + 136
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x20921fa10 thread_start + 8

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x20921f9fc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x20921f9fc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x20921f9fc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x20921f9fc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
x0: 0x000000013f035a00   x1: 0x0000000199ac8db2   x2: 0x000000013f03f400   x3: 0x000000016dc1dc98
x4: 0x0000000000000010   x5: 0x00000001f5afba60   x6: 0x0000000000000053   x7: 0x0000000000000000
x8: 0x00000002817921c0   x9: 0x0000000000000000  x10: 0x6ae100013f035a00  x11: 0x000000000000001f
x12: 0x0000000000664000  x13: 0x000000014380c390  x14: 0x0000000000000000  x15: 0x0000000000000000
x16: 0x0000000000000000  x17: 0x00000001f28371b8  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x000000013f03f400
x20: 0x000000013e8098b0  x21: 0x00000002817921c0  x22: 0x0000000000000058  x23: 0x00000000000001b8
x24: 0x00000001ef703000  x25: 0x0000000300000007  x26: 0x0000000000000058  x27: 0x0000000000000003
x28: 0x0000000000000000   fp: 0x000000016dc1de10   lr: 0x00000001a17fd2ac
sp: 0x000000016dc1dbd0   pc: 0x00000001976f4820 cpsr: 0x20001000
far: 0x0000000000000010  esr: 0x92000006 (Data Abort) byte read Translation fault

Binary Images:
0x102a20000 -        0x102a2bfff libobjc-trampolines.dylib arm64e  \<26d68e81199a300dbc1530ba4630a611\> /private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/lib/libobjc-trampolines.dylib
0x102910000 -        0x10291ffff FBLPromises arm64  \<475bfc4698e93a7da7efa1531cdb76fe\> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/47150E9B-4376-454B-B159-848CD58B9C2F/LifeLog.app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises
0x102984000 -        0x10299ffff GoogleUtilities arm64  \<18d1df95dfc5348ba58bc3941f858c01\> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/47150E9B-4376-454B-B159-848CD58B9C2F/LifeLog.app/Frameworks/GoogleUtilities.framework/GoogleUtilities
0x1028f8000 -        0x1028fffff nanopb arm64  \<a918b9f7da2d368d90fd7ebf9bb4570c\> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/47150E9B-4376-454B-B159-848CD58B9C2F/LifeLog.app/Frameworks/nanopb.framework/nanopb
0x1021e0000 -        0x102733fff LifeLog arm64  \<7936923f036f3407aff89ee875898991\> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/47150E9B-4376-454B-B159-848CD58B9C2F/LifeLog.app/LifeLog
0x1976f0000 -        0x19773dfe0 libobjc.A.dylib arm64e  \<98c1e5b8c56e3b9c9783b0fef8f999ee\> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x1a1551000 -        0x1a3026fff UIKitCore arm64e  \<99ad2a319360369f9c0ba7a0af33e2e7\> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore
0x19f326000 -        0x19f852fff CoreFoundation arm64e  \<be405d8a546437a3a17e1068db404b23\> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x1e28af000 -        0x1e28b7fff GraphicsServices arm64e  \<7d6f670c0e4b32158b4e599ef1ab9ed2\> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x1a3027000 -        0x1a4f5afff SwiftUI arm64e  \<8152ba981fb73a7f8059bd1ad9b7b7b2\> /System/Library/Frameworks/SwiftUI.framework/SwiftUI
0x1c2079000 -        0x1c2100b5b dyld arm64e  \<630c2209dfd73c72b0a9e856c560f123\> /usr/lib/dyld
0x0 - 0xffffffffffffffff ??? unknown-arch  \<00000000000000000000000000000000\> ???
0x1e69f4000 -        0x1e6a2cfef libsystem_kernel.dylib arm64e  \<55f2cc41248837bdbb95ea2ffd7611ae\> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x19e2c0000 -        0x19ee1ffff Foundation arm64e  \<c52a963060f13d48a6c350a20de78c6a\> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x20921e000 -        0x209229ff3 libsystem_pthread.dylib arm64e  \<e9ae8dcfc2b635d7af24e008b8034e31\> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
0x1a735c000 -        0x1a73d9ff3 libsystem_c.dylib arm64e  \<6e5a7692c1e935adb20bc307991df11c\> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x1a03fd000 -        0x1a07d8fff CFNetwork arm64e  \<707e82b749fc31aaa493f47aac5c7c41\> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
```

I am seeking your expertise in interpreting this crash report and providing insights into the possible cause of the crash. If anyone has experience dealing with similar issues or can suggest troubleshooting steps, I would greatly appreciate your assistance.

Thank you in advance for your time and support.

Best regards

I checked the main thread initialization part and didn't see any major problems. I also investigated objc_msgSend, but could not find the specific cause.

Comment: Also check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10026835/application-exited-abnormally-with-signal-11-segmentation-fault-11 as it mentions "SIGNAL 11 Segmentation fault: 11"

Comment: `objc_msgSend` isn't your issue, it's your symptom. This function is what implements all method invocation ("message sending") in Objective C, including when you call ObjC APIs from Swift. Most likely, the object your trying to send a message to no longer exists. As the linked question explains, this is a memory corruption issue somewhere else in your program. This is just where it surfaces.