# App crashes while not connected through Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, crash-reports

I got strange behavior for iOS App.
My App crashes only when it is not connected through XCode. Also, It crashes only after coming from back ground to foreground. I just gone through the crash log, as many links suggested to do that.

I am now unable to find out what the crash log says.

```
Jun  1 09:22:28 unknown SpringBoard[15] <Notice>: Posting 'com.apple.iokit.hid.displayStatus' notifyState=0

Jun  1 09:22:28 unknown SpringBoard[15] <Notice>: MultitouchHID: detection mode: 0->255

Jun  1 09:22:28 unknown UserEventAgent[12] <Warning>: DEBUG: Changing screen blanked state: 1

Jun  1 09:22:28 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: [000070.133242]: AppleDPDisplay::setLCDStateGated:(0x81b4a000) Disabling

Jun  1 09:22:28 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: [000000.000163]: AppleDPDisplay::terminateLink:(0x81b4a000) Waited 0 ms for display to disable

Jun  1 09:22:28 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: [000000.000020]: AppleDPDisplay::terminateLink:(0x81b4a000) ret=0x00000000

Jun  1 09:22:28 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: [000000.000703]: AppleDPDisplay::deviceTerminated:(0x81b4a000) device=0xb4fcd300

Jun  1 09:22:28 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: [000000.000099]: AppleDPDisplay::setPower:(0x81b4a000) enable=0 ret=0x00000000

Jun  1 09:22:28 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: [000000.000020]: AppleDPDisplay::setLCDStateGated:(0x81b4a000) enable=0 ret=0x00000000

Jun  1 09:22:29 unknown SpringBoard[15] <Notice>: Posting 'com.apple.iokit.hid.displayStatus' notifyState=1

Jun  1 09:22:29 unknown UserEventAgent[12] <Warning>: DEBUG: Changing screen blanked state: 0

Jun  1 09:22:29 unknown SpringBoard[15] <Notice>: MultitouchHID: detection mode: 255->0 (deferring until bootloaded)

Jun  1 09:22:29 unknown SpringBoard[15] <Notice>: MultitouchHID: device bootloaded

Jun  1 09:22:29 unknown SpringBoard[15] <Notice>: MultitouchHID: detection mode: 0->0

Jun  1 09:22:29 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: set_crc_notification_state 0

Jun  1 09:22:29 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: [000001.383400]: AppleDPDisplay::setLCDStateGated:(0x81b4a000) Enabling

Jun  1 09:22:29 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: [000000.001806]: AppleDPDisplay::setPower:(0x81b4a000) setting bl deadline for 193 ms from now

Jun  1 09:22:29 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: [000000.000027]: AppleDPDisplay::setPower:(0x81b4a000) enable=1 ret=0x00000000

Jun  1 09:22:29 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: [000000.000018]: AppleDPDisplay::setLCDStateGated:(0x81b4a000) enable=1 ret=0x00000000

Jun  1 09:22:30 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: [000000.052701]: AppleDPDisplay::devicePublished:(0x81b4a000) newDevice=0x8d3ee000

Jun  1 09:22:30 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: [000000.023734]: AppleDPDisplay::trainLink:(0x81b4a000) Waited 23 ms for link training

Jun  1 09:22:30 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: [000000.000174]: AppleDPDisplay::initiateLink:(0x81b4a000) Waited 78 ms for display to enable

Jun  1 09:22:30 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: [000000.000020]: AppleDPDisplay::initiateLink:(0x81b4a000) _dpDevice=0x8d3ee000 ret=0x00000000

Jun  1 09:22:37 unknown ReportCrash[9152] <Notice>: Formulating crash report for process XYZ[9143]

Jun  1 09:22:37 unknown ReportCrash[9152] <Notice>: Saved crashreport to /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/XYZ_2012-06-01-092237_The-new-iPad.plist using uid: 
0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 501 egid: 0

Jun  1 09:22:37 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Warning>: 
(UIKitApplication:com.company.test[0xe951]) Job appears to have crashed: Segmentation fault: 11

Jun  1 09:22:37 unknown SpringBoard[15] <Warning>: Application 'XYZ' exited abnormally with signal 11: Segmentation fault: 11
```

Can anyone here read this and hint me towards some solution or work arounds ??

Comment: might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1849929/signal-11-segmentation-fault-on-iphone-app-exit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try add a NSZombieEnabled. For to do this:

1) Press cmd + Shift + ,

2) In left panel click a "Run {app name}"

3) At right choose Diagnostics"

4) Set checkbox at "Enable Zombie Objects"

5) Retry a crash, then you can debug a error with XCode